# Classes in C++ and Constructor Functions

Tags: c++, class, constructor

Can a class can have several default constructor functions? I was wondering because I would think that one of anything can only have one default function by definition of "default", but I'm not too sure.

Comment: If it had several default constructors, which would it choose?

Comment: By a default constructor do you mean one that accepts no parameters? If so then that can't have more than one as how would the compiler tell which one you meant?

Comment: @T.Kiley, By definition, it's one that can be called with no arguments. That still means default arguments are allowed.

Comment: @chris Well yeah, but I thought I'd confirm the definition in case there is a misunderstanding :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A class can have several default constructors. However in that case, you cannot default-construct it because when trying to do so, you'd run into an ambiguity:

```
class C
{
public:
  C(); // a default constructor
  C(int = 0); // another default constructor
};

C c1; // error: ambiguity; both C::C() or C::C(int) with the default argument 0 match
C c2(0); // OK, no ambiguity
```

Note however that you cannot have two constructors with the same signature:

```
class C2
{
public:
  C2() {}
  C2() {} // error: C2::C2() already defined
};
```

Comment: In my compiler (GCC 4.8.1), `std::is_default_constructible` is false for your example.  According to [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_default_constructible), the trait checks whether "the class has an accessible default constructor". Either the compiler or that website are wrong, or this is somehow UB.

Comment: @KerrekSB, It's defined in terms of `std::is_constructible<T>::value` and the closest thing I can find is § 20.9.4.3/6, but I'm not sure if that's the right one to be using.

Comment: @BenVoigt, Good thing it can quickly and easily be edited and proven with a reference, unlike another site I'm thinking of.

Comment: @chris: That's the right section in the Standard.  `std::is_default_constructible<C>` indicates whether `C c;` is well-formed.  It isn't (because of ambiguity), so `std::is_default_constructible<C>` is rightly false even though default constructors exist and are accessible.

Comment: @BenVoigt: What's the definition of `is_constructible`? Weirdly I can't find it at all in the standard. There's just a table that says "see below", but I don't see "below".

Comment: @KerrekSB, That would be the section I referenced. I was just slightly thrown off by the use of `std::add_rvalue_reference`. Basically, `std::is_default_constructible` boils down to `T t();` being well-formed, except when simplified like that, it becomes a function, which is explicitly prevented in the wording below.

Comment: @chris: Could it be boiled down to the expression `T()` being well-formed?

Comment: @celtschk, I suppose, yes, I was just sticking as closely to the standard as possible, but taking out the text for arguments that appear in `std::is_constructible` because there are none for default construction.